# Authintication upload files using Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

hello I have two difference projects one project have only authentication and other have only fileupload and upload to personal folder per user(work fine from admin mode)and I want to connect with one project.
On the second project I have create a fuction where create new personal folder for any user where want upload files using `user_id`,`user_username` (I have to many similars ways to do this function and this is for test).

that I don't know is how to take `user_id` or `user_name` of login user and how to use this in views.py to my fuction for `generate_path`.
I thing so maybe like this `user = Photo.objects.get(user__id=user_id)`but I am not sure

```
def generate_path(user):
    return "/{0}/img".format(user.username)


class Photo(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to=generate_path(self.user)))
```

views.py

```
@login_required
class BasicUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        photoslist = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'index.html', {'photos': photoslist})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you would like to get the logon user in your view.
In Django, if the user logon successfully, then the object is available in request.user which you can use to do retrieve the records in Photo as you mentioned.

```
def get(self, request):
    # retrieve photos from logon user
    Photo.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: in  `generate_path `I use `user_id `right ?that id must be define in the view with some way to image save in the right path ?or if user login then take automate from Django ?

Comment: you need to make sure that the user field is saved when posting